# How to launch specific task from input variable in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm trying to create a launch configuration where an environment variable is dynamically determined by a shell script. Even though a [command variable](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference#_command-variables) can start a task via `workbench.action.tasks.runTask`, it doesn't seem to be possible to specify which task to run. [Input variables](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference#_input-variables) seem to be a little more flexible in that regard, but I can't seem to get it to work. Here is what I got:

launch.json:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Launch",
            "type": "go",
            "request": "launch",
            "mode": "auto",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/main.go",
            "env": {
                "XXX": "${input:foo}"
            },
            "args": []
        }
    ],
    "inputs": [
        {
            "type": "command",
            "id": "foo",
            "command": "workbench.action.tasks.runTask",
            "args": {
                "args": "bar",
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

tasks.json:

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "bar",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "find /dev -name 'myspecialdevice*' -maxdepth 1"
        }
    ]
}
```

The issue is that the user is still queried for which task to run. I'm most insecure about the `inputs.args` section of the launch.json. I don't really know what the key value should be. Perhaps the [implementation](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/blob/master/src/vs/workbench/contrib/tasks/electron-browser/task.contribution.ts#L553) helps to figure this out?

Comment: Getting the `command` input type to work has also stumped me. The `pickString` example from https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference#_input-variables worked like a charm, but there is no example for `command` and every logical attempt has so far failed...does this even work? Working with 1.39.2 Visual Studio Code on Ubuntu 18.04.

Answer (score 6):

*This answer not really relates to make use of a vscode task, but your introducting sentence offers the motivation/what is intended to be solved.*

I was faced to the same question and was wondering about [vscode's input type:command](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference#_input-variables). It offers a way to embed a (custom) *vscode command* -- which looks like a powerfull mechanism to embed a (custom) extension here. But I didn't found a builtin command that simply executes a shell script and returns it stdout. Thus an extension to capture the output of a shell command is imho required todo the trick.

E.g. https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=augustocdias.tasks-shell-input
provides a command `shellCommand.execute` doing exactly this.

```json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Launch",
            "type": "go",
            "request": "launch",
            "mode": "auto",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/main.go",
            "env": {
                "XXX": "${input:foo}"
            },
            "args": []
        }
    ],
    "inputs": [
        {
            "id": "foo",
            "type": "command",
            "command": "shellCommand.execute",
            "args": {
                "command": "find /dev -name 'myspecialdevice*' -maxdepth 1",
                "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
                /* To prevent user from selecting output (if there is just
                   one line printed by command), un-comment next line */
                //"useSingleResult": true
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

*(Inspired by https://stackoverflow.com/a/58930746/1903441)*

Answer (score 1):

In your `launch.json`, try replacing

```
"args": {
    "args": "bar",
}
```

with

```
"args": "bar"
```

Comment: I think that the value for args should be an array, cause you could have multiple arguments. In this case though, if it's just one argument, the omitting the `[]` should still work

Comment: Works for me with a string, doesn't work for me with a list. There are other commands that work with a list, but not this one. You can request a change at https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues - I agree that consistency would be nice.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that in vscode, you cannot pass a return or even an environment variable from `task.json` to `launch.json`. But you can use a file as a intermediate.

For example, in `task.json`:

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "bar",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "find /dev -name 'myspecialdevice*' -maxdepth 1 > ${workspaceFolder}/.vscode/temp"
        }
    ]
}
```

In `launch.json` you set bar as `preLaunchTask`, and later access the file using `inputs`, like this:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Launch",
            "type": "go",
            "request": "launch",
            "mode": "auto",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/main.go",
            "env": {
                "XXX": "${input:foo}"
            },
            "args": [],
            "preLaunchTask": "bar",
        }
    ],
    "inputs": [
        {
            "id": "foo",
            "type": "command",
            "command": "extension.commandvariable.file.content",
            "args": {
                "fileName": "${workspaceFolder}/.vscode/temp",
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

To get the comment working, just install this extension: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.command-variable

Comment: This worked great. Though note the insane `fileName` capitalisation. This tripped me up for ages, and it doesn't have good error checking so the only error you get is `ENOENT`.