# Variable from file for launch configuration

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there a way to set a variable in a launch configuration, that comes from a file, without an extension?

I've seen the following:

- default vscode variables, e.g. `${file}`
- vscode input prompt or picker
- vscode extension command

But neither seems to allow me to use a variable of my own, from some external data. In my case, i just want to load a port from a json configuration, so i don't need to copy it into the launch configuration: `"url": "http://something:${coolPeoplePort}"`. The server uses the port from that same file.

I've found [this overly workflow specific way](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging#_automatically-open-a-uri-when-debugging-a-server-program). This could potentially be abused, by running some program, that puts the variable on stdout. Why this feature is so specific to this application, i don't understand. It might work, because it seems to be precisely and only for putting ports into chrome debug URIs. Unlike the intention, the node program wouldn't be a webserver, and it would feel like i am using "happy hippo special case #5643", which is typically neither clean, future-proof, nor robust.

There are [extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58747689/using-a-shell-command-as-vscode-task-variable-value) that provide a multitude of ways to deal with this, but i don't want to install one, as it is a rather minor use case (i just don't want to copy some data to two places).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In extension [Command Variable](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.command-variable#file-content-json-property) v1.10.0 I have added the possibility to extract a value from a JSON file.

Example `config.json` file

```json
{
  "log": "foobar.log",
  "server1": {
    "port": 5011
  },
  "server2": {
    "port": 5023
  }
}
```

In your `task.json` you want to use the server1 port value:

```json
{
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "label": "echo Server1Port",
      "type": "shell",
      "command": "echo",
      "args": [
        "${input:configServer1Port}"
      ],
      "problemMatcher": []
    }
  ],
  "inputs": [
    {
      "id": "configServer1Port",
      "type": "command",
      "command": "extension.commandvariable.file.content",
      "args": {
        "fileName": "${workspaceFolder}/config.json",
        "json": "content.server1.port",
        "default": "4321"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Originally, i didn't want to add another extension for this, but it seems to be the only way. Thanks, i'll consider it.

Comment: @Doofus Much functionality of VSC is from extensions, many are part of the default install

Comment: Yes, but third-party extensions always come with the typical problems: what, if they stop being maintained? What, if they are incompatible with another? Are they buggy? Are they secure/safe? It's often not that big of a problem, and i might just install it, hence why i accepted your answer. Still, i always try to use existing features first. When those possibilities are exhausted, i think about how dearly i need the feature, and then potentially get an extension, if possible.