# VSCode deal the command parameter as literal

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-code

I want to build a Rasterizer project with opencv.The below command work well in shell(some parameter is omitted, such as `-static-libgcc`):

```cpp
g++ *.cpp -g -o Rasterizer `pkg-config --libs opencv`
```

However, when I want to do the same thing with VSCode, it fails and throw an error:

```cpp
g++: error: `pkg-config --libs opencv`: No such file or directory
```

The log tells me that the executed task in VSCode is(also omit some parameters)

```cpp
g++ *.cpp -g -o Rasterizer '`pkg-config --libs opencv`'
```

I think the reason is the parameter

```
`pkg-config --libs opencv`
```

is surrounded by a pair of quotes `'` and saw as literal. How can I solve this problem?

**The whole error message can be seen here:**

```
> Executing task: g++ /home/cs18/GAMES101/pa1/*.cpp -fdiagnostics-color=always -g -o /home/cs18/GAMES101/pa1/build/main -static-libgcc -fexec-charset=GBK '`pkg-config --libs opencv`' <

g++: error: `pkg-config --libs opencv`: No such file or directory
The terminal process "/bin/bash '-c', 'g++ /home/cs18/GAMES101/pa1/*.cpp -fdiagnostics-color=always -g -o /home/cs18/GAMES101/pa1/build/main -static-libgcc -fexec-charset=GBK '`pkg-config --libs opencv`''" failed to launch (exit code: 1).
```

My VSCode configuration file `task.json`:

```json
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "shell",
            "label": "C/C++: g++ build active file",
            "command": "g++",
            "args": [
                "${fileDirname}/*.cpp",
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-g",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/build/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
                "-static-libgcc",
                "-fexec-charset=GBK",
                "`pkg-config --libs opencv`"
            ],
            "presentation": { 
                "echo": true,
                "reveal": "always", 
                "focus": false, 
                "panel": "new" 
            },
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

let's try this .

```
   {
        "tasks": [
            {
                "type": "shell",
                "label": "C/C++: g++ build active file",
                "command": "g++",
                "args": [
                    "${fileDirname}/*.cpp",
                    "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                    "-g",
                    "-o",
                    "${fileDirname}/build/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
                    "-static-libgcc",
                    "-fexec-charset=GBK",
                    "${PKG_RET}"
                ],
       "options": {
            "env": {
                "PKG_RET": "${input:pkg_ret}"
            }
        },
                "presentation": { 
                    "echo": true,
                    "reveal": "always", 
                    "focus": false, 
                    "panel": "new" 
                },
                "options": {
                    "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
                },
                "problemMatcher": [
                    "$gcc"
                ],
                "group": {
                    "kind": "build",
                    "isDefault": true
                },
                "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
            }
        ],
        "version": "2.0.0"
    },
"inputs": [
    {
        "id": "pkg_ret",
        "type": "command",
        "command": "shellCommand.execute",
        "args": {
            "command": "pkg-config --libs opencv"
        }
    }
]
```

refer : [Using a shell command as VSCode task variable value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58747689/using-a-shell-command-as-vscode-task-variable-value)