# How to evaluate the shell command and use its output as value for an option in launch.json

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I have the following configuration in my `launch.json` to debug my C++ program, but it's kind of cumbersome to find the PID each time.

```json
{
    "type": "lldb",
    "request": "attach",
    "name": "BSServer",
    "pid": "${command:pickMyProcess}" 
},
```

To find the PID, I use a custom shell command like this: `pgrep -f 0f9eb747cc6766a0035a93f0`. Is there any way to directly feed the output of this command to the `pid` option in `launch.json`?

Something like this:

```json
{
    "type": "lldb",
    "request": "attach",
    "name": "BSServer",
    "pid": "${shellCommand:pgrep -f 0f9eb747cc6766a0035a93f0}" 
},
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using a shell command as VSCode task variable value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58747689/using-a-shell-command-as-vscode-task-variable-value)

Answer (score 1):

This question has already been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58747689/using-a-shell-command-as-vscode-task-variable-value).

### Solution:

- Install the [Task Shell Input](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=augustocdias.tasks-shell-input) extension
- Use something like `"MYARCH": "${input:get_arch}"` in your fields
- Define the command that `get_arch` should run in your inputs list
- Remember to add `useFirstResult: true` in the `args` section of your input to avoid the need for user interaction when running the command